# Returning struct containing array

Tags: c, linux, gcc, language-lawyer

The following simple code segfaults under gcc 4.4.4

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct Foo Foo;
struct Foo {
    char f[25];
};

Foo foo(){
    Foo f = {"Hello, World!"};
    return f;
}

int main(){
    printf("%s\n", foo().f);
}
```

Changing the final line to

```
 Foo f = foo(); printf("%s\n", f.f);
```

Works fine. Both versions work when compiled with `-std=c99`. Am I simply invoking undefined behavior, or has something in the standard changed, which permits the code to work under C99? Why does is crash under C89?

Comment: If you turn on warnings, I get `warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char[25]’`

Comment: Remember that `printf` is one of those funny vararg functions. If it was being passed to a normal function that took a `char*` argument, then it should decay nicely. But I think it's interacting funny with `printf`.

Comment: It doesn't `Invalid use of non-lvalue array`

Comment: I'm on "gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3". What are you using?

Comment: In C++, that would be OK. You can call members of a temporary. But maybe C has different rules about temporaries.

Comment: You know, I don't think I've every seen a construction like `foo().f` in a *c* program before. It would be very natural in a c++ program, of course.

Comment: In *C*, is there anything that you are allowed to do with a temporary, other than copy it by value into another location (into a function or into a local variable)? Maybe the answer is No.

Comment: Added the "language-lawyer" tag. Since we seem to be needing one of those to answer this...

Comment: @AaronMcDaid that warning happens in C89 mode, but not c99.  And, interestingly, only in the first construction, not after storing it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe the behavior is undefined both in C89/C90 and in C99.

`foo().f` is an expression of array type, specifically `char[25]`.  [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.3.2.1p3 says:

> Except when it is the operand of the **sizeof** operator or the unary
>   **&** operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
>   expression that has type "array of *type*" is converted to an
>   expression with type "pointer to *type*" that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
>   has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

The problem in this particular case (an array that's an element of a structure returned by a function) is that there is no "array object".  Function results are returned by value, so the result of calling `foo()` is a *value* of type `struct Foo`, and `foo().f` is a value (not an lvalue) of type `char[25]`.

This is, as far as I know, the only case in C (up to C99) where you can have a non-lvalue expression of array type.  I'd say that the behavior of attempting to access it is undefined by omission, likely because the authors of the standard (understandably IMHO) didn't think of this case.  You're likely to see different behaviors at different optimization settings.

The new 2011 C standard patches this corner case by inventing a new storage class.  [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the link is to a late pre-C11 draft) says in 6.2.4p8:

> A non-lvalue expression with structure or union type, where the 
>   structure or union contains a member with array type (including,
>   recursively, members of all contained structures and unions) refers to
>   an object with automatic storage duration and *temporary lifetime*.
>   Its lifetime begins when the expression is evaluated  and its initial
>   value is the value of the expression. Its lifetime ends when the
>   evaluation of the containing full expression or full declarator ends.
>   Any attempt to modify an object with temporary lifetime results in
>   undefined behavior.

So the program's behavior is well defined in C11.  Until you're able to get a C11-conforming compiler, though, your best bet is probably to store the result of the function in a local object (assuming your goal is working code rather than breaking compilers):

```
[...]
int main(void ) {
    struct Foo temp = foo();
    printf("%s\n", temp.f);
}
```

Comment: +1. A question though. Does the C11 standard say anything about the constness of these expressions? I'm guessing you can only take a `const` pointer to them? e.g. `bar(&foo());` and `baz(foo().f);` where bar and baz are `void bar(const Foo *);` and `void baz(const char *);`

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: I don't think so.  If it were `const`, it wouldn't be necessary to day that attempting to modify it has undefined behavior.

Comment: I'd interpret that the other way around. (But I think it's a bit ambiguous.) I think it's "The pointer is to a const type, and if you cast it to a non-const type and try to modify through it, then the behaviour is undefined". My logic is: if you're not supposed to modify it, shouldn't the type be `const`?

Comment: .. but, in short, that final sentence answers my underlying question. Thanks @KeithThompson

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: It's like string literals: they're not `const`, but modifying them is undefined.  (That's for historical reasons; I'm not sure why they didn't make function results `const`.)

Answer (score 13):

`printf` is a bit funny, because it's one of those functions that takes [varargs](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.basetechref%2Fdoc%2Fbasetrf2%2Fvarargs.htm). So let's break it down by writing a helper function `bar`. We'll return to `printf` later.

(I'm using "gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3")

```
void bar(const char *t) {
    printf("bar: %s\n", t);
}
```

and calling that instead:

```
bar(foo().f); // error: invalid use of non-lvalue array
```

OK, that gives an error. In C and C++, you are not allowed to pass an array *by value*. You can work around this limitation by putting the array inside a struct, for example `void bar2(Foo f) {...}`

But we're not using that workaround - we're not allowed to pass in the array by value. Now, you might think it should decay to a `char*`, allowing you to pass the array by reference. But decay only works if the array has an address (i.e. is an lvalue). But *temporaries*, such as the return values from function, live in a magic land where they don't have an address. Therefore you can't take the address `&` of a temporary. In short, we're not allowed to take the address of a temporary, and hence it can't decay to a pointer. We are unable to pass it by value (because it's an array), nor by reference (because it's a temporary).

I found that the following code worked:

```
bar(&(foo().f[0]));
```

but to be honest I think that's suspect. Hasn't this broken the rules I just listed?

And just to be complete, this works perfectly as it should:

```
Foo f = foo();
bar(f.f);
```

The variable `f` is not a temporary and hence we can (implicitly, during decay) takes its address.

#### printf, 32-bit versus 64-bit, and weirdness

I promised to mention `printf` again. According to the above, it should refuse to pass foo().f to any function (including printf). But printf is funny because it's one of those vararg functions. gcc allowed itself to pass the array *by value* to the printf.

When I first compiled and ran the code, it was in 64-bit mode. I didn't see confirmation of my theory until I compiled in 32-bit (`-m32` to gcc). Sure enough I got a segfault, as in the original question. (I had been getting some gibberish output, but no segfault, when in 64 bits).

I implemented my own `my_printf` (with the vararg nonsense) which printed the actual value of the `char *` before trying to print the letters pointed at by the `char*`. I called it like so:

```
my_printf("%s\n", f.f);
my_printf("%s\n", foo().f);
```

and this is the output I got ([code on ideone](http://ideone.com/WVc9t)):

```
arg = 0xffc14eb3        // my_printf("%s\n", f.f); // worked fine
string = Hello, World!
arg = 0x6c6c6548        // my_printf("%s\n", foo().f); // it's about to crash!
Segmentation fault
```

The first pointer value `0xffc14eb3` is correct (it points to the characters "Hello, world!"), but look at the second `0x6c6c6548`. That's the ASCII codes for `Hell` (reverse order - little endianness or something like that). It has copied the array *by value* into printf and the first four bytes have been interpreted as a 32-bit pointer or integer. This pointer doesn't point anywhere sensible and hence the program crashes when it attempts to access that location.

I think this is in violation of the standard, simply by virtue of the fact that we're not supposed to be allowed to copy arrays by value.

Comment: It seems like, unable to decay, printf actually gets passed the array by value. I'm not implying that the behavior is legal, but `printf("%c%c%c%c\n", foo().f);` prints every `sizeof(int)`th character in the string. I'm really interested in finding some reference in the standard to clear this up.

Comment: I just noticed the same thing. See the end of my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS X 10.7.2, both GCC/LLVM 4.2.1 ('i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)') and GCC 4.6.1 (which I built) compile the code without warnings (under `-Wall -Wextra`), in both 32-bit and 64-bit modes. The programs all run without crashing.  This is what I'd expect; the code looks fine to me.

Maybe the problem on Ubuntu is a bug in the specific version of GCC that has since been fixed?

Comment: I just tried with gcc 4.6.2 (compiled myself) on Ubuntu. I got a segfault again, but  output was slightly different. I didn't get the `0x6c6c6548 == "Hell"` I got in my other answer. I got `0xffffffff`. This is all pretty weird.

Comment: I dug out a SuSE VM (Linux ids1150srvr 2.6.16.60-0.21-smp #1 SMP Tue May 6 12:41:02 UTC 2008 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux) and GCC 4.1.2 and the test program compiled without warnings and ran successfully.  So, the problem is definitely somewhat system-specific.  It certainly isn't simply Linux vs the rest.  That's no extra help though.  If you're invoking undefined behaviour (despite my thoughts that you probably aren't), then anything can happen and it is valid.