# return struct from function

Tags: c, function, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Returning struct containing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774753/returning-struct-containing-array)

I have some simple code:

```
struct s {
    char str[128];
};

struct s foo()
{
    struct s s = { "some string" };
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", foo().str);
    return 0;
}
```

but it's perform a warning:

> warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2
>   has type ‘char[128]’ [-Wformat]

if i change main function like that

```
int main()
{
    struct s s = foo();
    printf("%s\n", s.str);
    return 0;
}
```

everything is ok. so, what the problem in the first code? thanks.

ps. im using gcc-4.7.0

pps. please notice, the problem occurs only with C compiler, with C++ everything is ok

Comment: btw, printf("%s\n", &foo().str[0]); is ok too

Comment: thanks, i'll try to understand that :)