# Convert milliseconds to timespec for GNU port

Tags: c, linux, datetime, gnu, timespec

I want to convert milliseconds into timespec structure used by GNU Linux. I have tried following code for the same.

```
  timespec GetTimeSpecValue(unsigned long milisec)
  {
    struct timespec req;
    //long sec = (milisecondtime /1000);
    time_t sec = (time_t)(milisec/1000);
    req->tv_sec = sec;
    req->tv_nsec = 0;
    return req;
  }
```

Running this code gives me the following error.

> expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘GetTimeSpecValue’

I have also include **time.h** file in the code.

Comment: Hm, either time.h was not included properly or there is missing semicolon somewhere above.

Comment: well, that is not the case. I have already gone through entire code and no such mistakes i found. :-(

Comment: There are multiple errors in your code. There is no `tv` declared which you try to return (I guess you want to return `req` instead). `req` is not a pointer but you try to access it via `->`. And you have to return `struct timespec` instead of `timespec`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `timespec` structure represents time in two portions — seconds and nanoseconds. Thus, the algorithm for conversion from milliseconds is pretty darn simple. One seconds has thousand milliseconds, one milliseconds has a thousand microseconds and one microsecond has a thousand nanoseconds, for which we are grateful to [SI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI). Therefore, we first need to divide milliseconds by a thousand to get a number of seconds. Say, for example, 1500 milliseconds / 1000 = 1.5 seconds. Given integer arithmetics (not a floating point), the remainder is dropped (i.e. 1500 / 1000 is equal to just 1, not 1.5). Then we need to take a remainder that denotes a number of milliseconds that is definitely less than one second, and multiply it by a million to convert it to nanoseconds. To get a remainder of dividing by 1000, we use a [module operator (`%`)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (i.e. `1500 % 1000 is equal to 500`). For example, let's convert 4321 milliseconds to seconds and nanoseconds:

1. 4321 (milliseconds) / 1000 = 4 (seconds)
2. 4321 (milliseconds) % 1000 = 321 (milliseconds)
3. 321 (milliseconds) * 1000000 = 321000000 (nanoseconds)

Knowing the above, the only thing that is left is to write a little bit of C code.  There are few things that you didn't get right:

1. In C, you have to prefix structure data types with `struct`. For example, instead of saying `timespec` you say `struct timespec`. In C++, however, you don't have to do it (unfortunately, in my opinion).
2. You cannot return structures from the function in C. Therefore, you need to pass a structure by pointer into a function that does something with that structure.

Edit: This contradicts ([Return a `struct` from a function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653072/return-a-struct-from-a-function-in-c)).

OK, enough talking. Below is a simple C code example:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void ms2ts(struct timespec *ts, unsigned long ms)
{
    ts->tv_sec = ms / 1000;
    ts->tv_nsec = (ms % 1000) * 1000000;
}

static void print_ts(unsigned long ms)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    ms2ts(&ts, ms);
    printf("%lu milliseconds is %ld seconds and %ld nanoseconds.\n",
           ms, ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
}

int main()
{
    print_ts(1000);
    print_ts(2500);
    print_ts(4321);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: Wouldn't this be better/faster to use `ts->tv_nsec = (ms - (ts->tv_sec * 1000)) * 1000000`, mod is a slow operation, especially on processors that do not have a hardware FPU

Comment: It should be noted that some functions, such as  pthread_mutex_cond_timedwait use a timestamp in tv_sec... this one had me scratching my head for a while.

Comment: I liked your explanation !.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
struct timespec GetTimeSpecValue(unsigned long millisec) {
    struct timespec req;
    req.tv_sec=  (time_t)(millisec/1000);
    req.tv_nsec = (millisec % 1000) * 1000000;
    return req;
}
```

I don't think struct timespec is typedef'ed,hence you need to prepend timespec with struct. And work out the nano second part if you want to be precise. Note that req is not a pointer. Thus members cannot be accessed with '->'

Comment: If he just gets milliseconds as input he cannot calculate any nanoseconds :).

Comment: True:) but he can update tv_nsec to as precise as possible given input is milli seconds. I'll fix it in my post

Comment: I had no use for nano second..and i corrected my mistake and your help did the trick..many thanks

Comment: @jparthj: If you have no use of nanoseconds, then you'll lose everything that is less than a second. It does sound very bad because a second is like "forever" for a computer, and saying that `1999` milliseconds is just one second may play a bad joke with your program. So be careful!

Answer (score 0):

Incorporating a few tweaks to the answer including Geoffrey's comment, the code below avoids divides for small delay and modulo for long delay:

```
void msec_to_timespec(unsigned long msec, struct timespec *ts)
{
    if (msec < 1000){
        ts->tv_sec = 0;
        ts->tv_nsec = msec * 1000000;
    }
    else {
        ts->tv_sec = msec / 1000;
        ts->tv_nsec = (msec - ts->tv_sec * 1000) * 1000000;
    }
}
```