# nanosleep does not work for values less than a second

Tags: c, linux, sleep

I have a program (mixed C and Fortran, although that doesn't seem to be relevant) that uses `nanosleep`. However, if my `timespec` has a `tv_sec` value of 0, it simply doesn't sleep. The `tv_nsec` value can be microseconds shy of a full second, but it does not sleep. (If `tv_sec` is `1`, it has no problem sleeping for a second.) Why would this be?

To make things more confusing, `usleep` with an appropriate value (i.e. `995000` usec) sleeps for just about a second as expected.

I'm seeing this problem with a RHEL 5.8 and a RHEL 6.4 box. Both are using `gcc`.

Here's the function that calls nanosleep:

```
void msleep(int *milliseconds)
{
    long usec;
    struct timespec sleep;
    usec = (*milliseconds) % 1000;
    sleep.tv_sec = (*milliseconds) / 1000;
    sleep.tv_nsec = 1000*usec;
    nanosleep(&sleep, NULL);
}
```

Obviously, I don't actually need nanosecond precision!

I've also tested a version in which I did check the return value; it was always `0` (success), and thus the `rem` output parameter (remaining time if interrupted) never got set.

Comment: Did you `strace` your program? Did you check return of [nanosleep(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) and used `errno` (e.g. thru `perror`) on failure. What kernel do you run? I am a bit sceptical: on all my applications,  `nanosleep` is working as documented. Please show some actual code!

Comment: You might like to show us how you call `nanosleep()` and how you initialise  the strcutures you pass into?

Comment: See new edit. Sorry, I should have explained the return value in my original post.

Comment: To me this looks as if your a missing 1000 some where: [ms]%1000=[ms] and [ms]*1000=[us] but you want [ns], so this should be `...tv_nsec = ((long)(milliseconds%1000)) * 1000 * 1000`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Where is `usec` declared?

Comment: I woudl expect `usec = (*milliseconds) * 1000;` and not `usec = (*milliseconds) % 1000;`

Comment: @chux this would overflow nsec in terms of that it might become larger then 10**-9 - 1secs.

Comment: Why pass the milliseconds as a pointer — why not just a value.  There are a million nanoseconds in a millisecond, so your sub-second delays are 1/1000th of what you want.

Comment: @alk, that was it! I can't believe I never noticed that before. That typo has existed in our code for at least five years... Anyway, if you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @alk All depends on the range of `int`, `long`.  IAC, using a right sized type, I would still expect `usec = (*milliseconds) * 1000`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, the pointer was because this is used in a compatibility routine called from Fortran, where the default (with `iso_c_binding` is to pass everything by reference. Obscure and unnecessary for the big picture, but that's where it came from.

Comment: @patrickvacek: fair enough — that's a perfectly good, though non-obvious, reason for the interface shown.  And it probably was not necessary to mention that in the original version of the question, though that's slightly borderline.

Comment: Thanks, all! That was fast. My only defense is that I didn't write the original code, although I have no explanation for how I didn't catch the glaring math error upon review of the code in light of the bug.

Comment: @chux: Regarding my use of "*overflow*", from `nanosleep()`'s (linux) man-page: `The value of the nanoseconds field must be in the range 0 to 999999999.`

Comment: @alk Regari`ngs me use of _"usec"_, which I was not assigning to any field,  was simply that to convert from msec to usec, code should `* 1000` rather than `% 1000` which is what your did in your fine answer.    Your answer used well-named variables like `ms_remaining` to convey the proper meaning of code's intent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing a factor of 1000.

Try this:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L /* shall be >= 199309L */

#include <time.h>

void msleep(int *milliseconds)  
{
  int ms_remaining = (*milliseconds) % 1000;
  long usec = ms_remaining * 1000;
  struct timespec ts_sleep;

  ts_sleep.tv_sec = (*milliseconds) / 1000;
  ts_sleep.tv_nsec = 1000*usec;
  nanosleep(&ts_sleep, NULL);
}
```

More compact:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L /* shall be >= 199309L */

#include <time.h>

void msleep(int * pmilliseconds)  
{
  struct timespec ts_sleep = 
  {
    *pmilliseconds / 1000,
    (*pmilliseconds % 1000) * 1000000L
  };

  nanosleep(&ts_sleep, NULL);
}
```

Finally a complete implementation including error handling and the case of `nanosleep()` being interrupted early:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L

#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int ms_sleep(unsigned int ms)
{
  int result = 0;

  {
    struct timespec ts_remaining =
    { 
      ms / 1000, 
      (ms % 1000) * 1000000L 
    };

    do
    {
      struct timespec ts_sleep = ts_remaining;
      result = nanosleep(&ts_sleep, &ts_remaining);
    } 
    while ((EINTR == errno) && (-1 == result));
  }

  if (-1 == result)
  {
    perror("nanosleep() failed");
  }

  return result;
}
```

Following a wrapper to fulfil the OP's requirements:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int ms_sleep(unsigned int);

void msleep(int * pms)
{
  int result = 0;

  if ((NULL == pms) || (0 > *pms)) /* Check for valid input. */
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
    result = -1;
  }
  else 
  {
    result = ms_sleep(*pms));
  }

  if (-1 == result)
  {
    perror("ms_sleep() failed");
    /* Exit and/or log error here. */
  }
}
```

---

Update (referring to [*chux*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux)'s comment below):

Assuming at least C99, this part of the above code

```
  struct timespec ts_sleep = 
  {
    *pmilliseconds / 1000,
    (*pmilliseconds % 1000) * 1000000L
  };
```

might better be written like this

```
  struct timespec ts_sleep = 
  {
    .tv_sec = *pmilliseconds / 1000,
    .tv_nsec = (*pmilliseconds % 1000) * 1000000L
  };
```

to not rely on the order of `struct timespec`'s members.

Comment: BTW: Are the order of Posix structures fixed?

Comment: @chux: Which kind of "*order*" are you referring to, please?

Comment: `struct timespec ts_sleep = { *pmilliseconds / 1000, (*pmilliseconds % 1000) * 1000000L };` only works if the order of the fields are fixed.  E.g.  `div_t` for C compliant code can have its two fields in either order.  So does Posix fix the field order of the structure?

Comment: @chux: Interesting question - up until now I assumed "yes", the order is well defined. After having read here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html I'm not so sure anymore. You might like to  pose this question at SO, though! ;-)

Comment: The third source code block you have ``while (EINTR == result);`` which should be ``while (result == -1 && errno == EINTR);``

Comment: @carveone: Oops, indeed! Thank you for notifying. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like below and it worked...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>   /* Needed for struct timespec */


int nsleep(long miliseconds)
{
   struct timespec req, rem;

   if(miliseconds > 999)
   {   
        req.tv_sec = (int)(miliseconds / 1000);                            /* Must be Non-Negative */
        req.tv_nsec = (miliseconds - ((long)req.tv_sec * 1000)) * 1000000; /* Must be in range of 0 to 999999999 */
   }   
   else
   {   
        req.tv_sec = 0;                         /* Must be Non-Negative */
        req.tv_nsec = miliseconds * 1000000;    /* Must be in range of 0 to 999999999 */
   }   

   return nanosleep(&req , &rem);
}

int main()
{
   int ret = nsleep(2500);
   printf("sleep result %d\n",ret);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method

```
  static void Sleep(long lMs){
       //Calculate the nanosecond
       long lRemainingMilliSecond = (lMs) % 1000;
       long lNanoSecond = lRemainingMilliSecond * 1000000;

       struct timespec ts_sleep,ts_remaining;

       ts_sleep.tv_sec = (lMs) / 1000;
       ts_sleep.tv_nsec = lNanoSecond;
       nanosleep(&ts_sleep, &ts_remaining);
}
```

The concept is explained better in the following page
[Convert milliseconds to timespec - GNU Porting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024623/convert-milliseconds-to-timespec-gnu-porting)