# error: incompatible types when initializing type 'struct taus88_t *' using type 'taus88_t'|?

Tags: c, gcc, types, incompatibility

I'm trying to compile the following C program using GCC and I'm getting an error
on line seven because the type `taus88_t*` is somehow not getting returned properly from the initializing function call called `make_taus88(seed);`?

`error: incompatible types when initializing type 'struct taus88_t *' using type 'taus88_t'|`

I've tried using `taus88_t TAUS88 = make_taus88(6346456);` but that gives more errors/warnings.

```
taus88main.c||In function 'main':|
taus88main.c|8|error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'taus88u32'|
taus88.h|21|note: expected 'struct taus88_t *' but argument is of type 'taus88_t'|
taus88main.c|9|error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'taus88f32'|
taus88.h|22|note: expected 'struct taus88_t *' but argument is of type 'taus88_t'|
taus_88_cpp\taus88main.c|9|warning: unused variable 'numberf32'|
taus_88_cpp\taus88main.c|8|warning: unused variable 'numberu32'|
```

The project is in 3 files below.

taus88main.c

```
#include "taus88.h"
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{

    taus88_t* TAUS88 = make_taus88(6346456);
    u32 numberu32 = taus88u32(TAUS88);
    f32 numberf32 = taus88f32(TAUS88);

    return 0;
}
```

taus88.h

```
#ifndef _COMMON_TAUS88_H
#define _COMMON_TAUS88_H

#include <stdint.h>
typedef int8_t    i8;
typedef int16_t   i16;
typedef int32_t   i32;
typedef int64_t   i64;

typedef uint8_t   u8;
typedef uint16_t  u16;
typedef uint32_t  u32;
typedef uint64_t  u64;
typedef float  f32;
typedef double f64;

typedef struct {u32 s1, s2, s3;} taus88_t;

taus88_t make_taus88(u32 seed);
u32 taus88u32(taus88_t *t);
f32 taus88f32(taus88_t *t);

#endif
```

taus88.c

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "taus88.h"

taus88_t make_taus88(u32 seed)
{
  taus88_t t;
  t.s1 = 1243598713U ^ seed; if (t.s1 <  2) t.s1 = 1243598713U;
  t.s2 = 3093459404U ^ seed; if (t.s2 <  8) t.s2 = 3093459404U;
  t.s3 = 1821928721U ^ seed; if (t.s3 < 16) t.s3 = 1821928721U;
  return t;
}

u32 taus88u32(taus88_t *t)
{
  t->s1 = ((t->s1 &  -2) << 12) ^ (((t->s1 << 13) ^  t->s1) >> 19);
  t->s2 = ((t->s2 &  -8) <<  4) ^ (((t->s2 <<  2) ^  t->s2) >> 25);
  t->s3 = ((t->s3 & -16) << 17) ^ (((t->s3 <<  3) ^  t->s3) >> 11);
  return t->s1 ^ t->s2 ^ t->s3;
}

f32 taus88f32(taus88_t *t)
{
  union {u32 i ; f32 f ;} u;
  u.i = 0x3F800000 | (taus88u32(t) >> 9);
  return u.f - 1.0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the main problem, the `taus88f32` function looks like it violates strict aliases rules, http://t.co/NH2GoPu6Sk.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour would that mean catastrophic failure later in life or just semantics?

Comment: The standard does not say that it's not valid, it says that it's undefined behavior ... these are quite different. Things that aren't valid require diagnostics; undefined behavior means that the standard doesn't define what it does ... but an implementation might.

Comment: "would that mean catastrophic failure later in life or just semantics?" -- it doesn't mean either. It means that the code isn't portable to every possible conforming C implementation, but that's obviously true because it makes assumptions about the internal representation of float values. If you only run it on the systems it is designed for, you're ok ... but knowing which ones those are could be a problem.

Comment: I have seen many argue that compilers support type punning like this just fine even though it is not standard but to know you need to go into the assembly and see what the compiler actually does. The article I linked in my answer goes into some of those details but at the end of the day the standard says it is `undefined behavior`.

Comment: The C standard is only "the end of the day" for language lawyers, not for professional programmers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the main problem here is that you are returning a `taus8_t` and trying to assign that to a `taus88_t *` which is not valid, if you need to use pointers for reasons that are not obvious from the code then the fix is as follows:

```
taus88_t* TAUS88 = malloc(sizeof(taus88_t)) ;

*TAUS88 = make_taus88(6346456);
```

You must remember to call `free` on the pointer though when you are done. A simpler approach, would be to skip using a pointer and do as follows:

```
taus88_t TAUS88 ;

TAUS88 = make_taus88(6346456);
u32 numberu32 = taus88u32(&TAUS88);
f32 numberf32 = taus88f32(&TAUS88);
```

Now you don't have to worry about calling `free` anymore.

The other issue that I pointed out is that most likely `taus88f32` violates [`strict aliasing`](http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html) rules.

Answer (score 0):

What about breaking `taus88_t* TAUS88 = make_taus88(6346456);` into two lines like

```
taus88_t* TAUS88;
*TAUS88 = make_taus88(6346456);
```

http://ideone.com/KVbf79

Comment: Well `taus88_t* TAUS88 = make_taus88(6346456);` is `pointer=type` but `*TAUS88 = make_taus88(6346456);` is `type=type` right? So it should work. What do you think?

Comment: I suggest you delete your post before you get downvoted, but thx for trying Snow Blind.

Comment: @SnowBlind Shafiks answer above compiles too but it crashes on the line given.

Comment: @user2555139 Dude first look at the title of your question, then downvote if an answer does not solve it. Runtime error has nothing to do with your original question which two of us answered already.

Comment: @SnowBlind You need to add a `malloc` for dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: I just upvoted you. I don't think I can downvote, takes >50 experience

Comment: Sigh. Just do `taus88_t TAUS88 = make_taus88(6346456);` -- there's no need for malloc. Then use &TAUS88 instead of TAUS88 in the subsequent calls.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `make_taus88` returns a `taus88_t` while you're trying to assign the result to a `taus88_t *` (pointer to `taus88_t`)

So, the first big problem is the `make_taus88` is defining `t` locally, then trying to return it.  You can't do that, because when `make_taus88` terminates, `t` will be out of scope.

The second is that you're returning a `taus88_t` and not a `taus88_t *`.

You can fix both by declaring `t` as `taus88_t *` in `make_taus88`, and initializing it dynamically using something like `malloc`.  Then, you can return `t` and it will be the correct type, and allocated on the heap, so that when `make_taus88` goes out of scope, the memory will still be available.

Note that in `make_taus88` you'd also have to change all references of the form `t.s1` to `t->s1`.

Comment: Nice feel free to make the changes in the code for me, I sort of understand what you mean but I'm no C fanatic and using Malloc is not my strongest suit.

Comment: You are not correct about returning a struct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653072/return-a-struct-from-a-function-in-c

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: You can return a struct if you want, but you can't assign it to a pointer to the struct.  And you still can't return an object that is stored on the stack.

Comment: " You can't do that, because when make_taus88 terminates, t will be out of scope."  Utter nonsense ... `t` is *copied* so its scope is irrrelevant.

Comment: "you can't assign it to a pointer to the struct" -- `*TAUS88` is not a pointer. "And you still can't return an object that is stored on the stack." -- You're simply wrong. You don't understand the language or its memory model. What you cannot return is the *address* of an object stored on the stack.

Comment: @user2555139 You would be wise to ignore this answer which, aside from the first sentence, is quite wrong. There's nothing wrong with make_tauss8, which was written by the competent Boost C programmers, just with your usage of it. You can simply do `taus88_t TAUS88 = make_taus88(6346456);` -- no need for malloc. But you need `u32 numberu32 = taus88u32(&TAUS88);
    f32 numberf32 = taus88f32(&TAUS88);`

Comment: @user2555139 Oops, that isn't Boost's version of make_tauss88; sorry about that. Still, I'm sure you didn't write it, and you shouldn't be changing it.

Comment: @JimBalter I looked at the boost library for this first actually and I couldn't find any way to use an example for Taus88 so I ended up with this junk of code instead. meh!