# Can a return type of a function be a structure?

Tags: c, struct, return-type

As the question suggests, can we return a structure from a function.

```
(struct spMat z) fastTranspose(struct spMat x[20])
{
 //did the process to store transpose in z

 return(z);
}
```

But now i am getting the error
error: expected identifier or '(' before 'struct'

Can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: `struct spMat fastTranspose [...]`?

Comment: Your function header should probably be `struct spMat fastTranspose (struct spMat x[])`. And yes, it's perfectly legal to return a structure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653072/return-a-struct-from-a-function-in-c

Comment: Thanks but can you tell me why i am getting this error on the line in which i have written --> return(z);

error: incompatible types when returning type 'struct spMat *' but 'struct spMat' was expected|

Comment: @user2696751 To answer this, we would need to see the "did the process to store transpose in z" code. Apparently you are returning a pointer to struct spMat whereas the function is expecting a return of struct spMat (no pointer).

Comment: If i write struct spMat* fastTranspose(struct spMat x[])
and in main i write c=fastTranspose(a).  Will z be copied in c or it's reference will be passed to c?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

```
struct spMat fastTranspose(struct spMat x[20])
{
     //declare a new struct if you need

     ...

     return x; // or the new struct which you declared before
}
```