# What is the maximum errno value?

Tags: c, errno

I want to build an unique error number, which consists of a random number and the `errno` of a system call. Example:

```
#define ERRID(ERRNO) ((uint32_t)rand() << 16 | (uint32_t)(ERRNO) & 0xFFFF)
```

I need to know how many bits are required to store an `errno` value.

I know it is defined as `int`. But the total number of errors is much lower than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 on a 64 bit system. On my Debian the maximum number seems to be 529.

```sh
dpkg -L linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common|
grep errno.h|
xargs cat|
awk '/^#define/{print $3}'|
sort -rn|
head -1
529
```

So `uint16_t` seems to be enough to store the `errno`.

But how to be sure? How can I find out how many errnos the operating system actually uses? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: **Why** you have to use `int16_t` if it's defined as `int`?! OS is free to add any error number wherever it wants in the next patch, two days after you released your application assuming it'll fit a 16 bit signed integer.

Comment: Can you use a structure, like `struct UniqueError { int randNumber, int errnoNumber };`? That is what I would consider, in terms of portability, instead of relying on the "maximum" value of errno (which might change over time and from system to system)

Comment: `int` is only 32 bits on 64-bit Linux.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Please read the first sentence of my question.

Comment: @Andreas That is the reason why I ask, if it is specified in a standard.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't make a good assumption about that. Yes you may set lower 16 bit to 0 and use higher 16 bit...or to use an hash code for your error name...

Comment: Although all the system I've seen started at 1 and incremented their errno values from there, and I havn't seen any system with an errno value > 1000 yet, there are no guarantees in any standard. That said, on linux there's an unwritten rule that errno can only go up to 4095

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no portable way to do this. POSIX (and C) allows the implementation to use all positive `int` values as error numbers, there is no constant for the maximum number used, and there may not be an integer type larger than `int`.

Comment: A `MAX_ERRNO` would be so simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass around a handle instead which contains **both** the `errno` error code and the random identifier (I assume you want this to be a unique ID in order to be able to identify specific instances of errors later…?)

```
struct ErrorID {
    int errno_error;
    int rand_id;
}

ErrorID this_func_can_fail()
{
    return (ErrorID){ .errno_error = errno, .rand_id = rand() };
}
```

This compiles:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ErrorID {
    int errno_error;
    int rand_id;
};

struct ErrorID this_func_can_fail()
{
    return (struct ErrorID){ .errno_error = errno, .rand_id = rand() };
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  this_func_can_fail();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code does not compile: `errid.c:6:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘this_func_can_fail’`

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it is possible to use structs as values in C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653072/return-a-struct-from-a-function-in-c

Comment: @ceving thanks. This wasn't intended as a complete compilable example – it's just a quick demo of my idea.

Comment: This doesn't work with C89, as there are no designated initializer to initialize a structure.

Comment: @LarsFriedrich then you rewrite it without field initializers. But I prefer to live in 2015 rather than 1989.