# What is the actual parameter list of member function created by the compiler?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, clang, clang++

I have a question about what value is passed to the C++ member function to invoke. When I disassemble a C++ member function like

```
void myClass::memberFunction() const;
```

I suppose it passed one implicit parameter `this` as the first and only parameter, but in fact, there could be two or more parameters passed.

I disassembled libobjc.A.dylib (iOS14.8-arm64e) with hopper. this function `class_rw::method() const` has no parameters, so I consider it pass only `this` pointer as the only parameter, but it has another (x1) parameter passed.

[image: disassemble libobjc.A.dylib-iOS14.8-arm64e]

Then actual code is opensource on apple
https://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-818.2/runtime/objc-runtime-new.mm.auto.html
And the snapshot is like
[image: class_rw::method() const]

It seems the compiler auto-generated additional variables for this member function.
My question is that:

1. This should only happen when we put the implementation in the class declaration right?
   This seems non-portable for classes that hides its implementation in another cpp file.
2. Is there a name for such an implicit added variable? I mean when we develop a compiler for c++, what do we call for such optimization?

Comment: fyi - there is a C++ ABI document [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html), however I do not know how closely compiler vendors follow it.

Comment: Disclaimer; I don't understand the assembly here at all. But maybe the second parameter is a pointer to the return variable. Like where to write the return structure, assuming it is a structure. There is an explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37186126/432492

Comment: Question is about AArch64 (64-bit ARM), which has its own ABI convention separate from Intel's. [ARM documentation](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102374/0101/Procedure-Call-Standard) says `x0` is used to pass `this` in C++, so, OP is asking what `x1` is used for.

Comment: Does your function return by value? If so and the returned value is not passed through a register, then there is typically a second "hidden" parameter that represents a pointer to the storage for the return value. In this live demo, it seems to be `x8`: https://godbolt.org/z/dGWcxs4qs.

Comment: Your code is from the Objective C runtime; this isn’t about C++ itself at all.

Answer (score 2):

From the [ARM64 procedure call standard](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ihi0055/d/#ResultReturn):

> ### Result Return
>
> The manner in which a result is returned from a function is determined by the type of that result:
>
> - If the type, T, of the result of a function is such that void func(T arg) would require that arg be passed as a value in a register (or set of registers) according to the rules in Parameter Passing, then the result is returned in the same registers as would be used for such an argument.
> - Otherwise, the caller shall reserve a block of memory of sufficient size and alignment to hold the result. The address of the memory block shall be passed as an additional argument to the function in x8. The callee may modify the result memory block at any point during the execution of the subroutine (there is no requirement for the callee to preserve the value stored in x8).

So this seems to be an example of the second type -- the return type `method_array_t` is something that is more than 16 bytes, so the caller allocates space for it and passes a pointer to that space as an extra argument.

Comment: This sounds entirely plausible for explaining "x1": +1.  It would definitely help if the OP created an [SSCCE](SSCCE.org) to verify this applies in his/her specific case.