# Why my struct created in function gets overwritten?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

How can I create structs in a function? I'm trying this way:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { char name[10]; } Item;

typedef struct { Item *item; } MyStruct;

MyStruct make(char *name) {
    MyStruct st;

    Item item;
    strcpy(item.name, name);
    st.item = &item;
    printf("name: %s\n", st.item->name);

    return st;
}

int main() {
    MyStruct s1, s2;
    s1 = make("hi");
    s2 = make("hey");

    printf("\nname: %s\n", s1.item->name);
    printf("name: %s\n", s2.item->name);
}
```

The output is:

```
name: hi
name: hey

name: hey
name: hey
```

The struct `s1` is being overwritten when I create `s2`. It looks that the address of the struct `st` on the function `make` is the same every time the function is called. Is it correct? I would like to avoid using `malloc` if possible.

**Edit**: The result is different on macOS and Linux, the output above is from Linux, below is from macOS. Why is it different?

```
name: hi
name: hey

name: p
name: p
```

Comment: You return a pointer to a local variable that doesn't exist any more when the function returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is misunderstanding pointers. Let's start with some very similar code that would work.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { char name[10]; } Item;

typedef struct { Item item; } MyStruct; // <--- Removed the *

MyStruct make(char *name) {
    MyStruct st;

    Item item;
    strncpy(item.name, name, 10);  // <--- strncpy because name[] is a fixed length
    st.item = item;                // <-- Removed the &; *copies* item into st
    printf("name: %s\n", st.item.name); // <-- . rather than ->

    return st;
}

int main() {
    MyStruct s1, s2;
    s1 = make("hi");
    s2 = make("hey");

    printf("\nname: %s\n", s1.item.name); // <-- . rather than ->
    printf("name: %s\n", s2.item.name);   // <-- . rather than ->
}
```

In this code I got rid of the pointers and everything should work. `Item` is 10 chars, and `MyStruct` is also 10 chars long. When you return it, those 10 chars of memory are copied, just like an int.

But you didn't do this; you added pointers. Since `item` is a local variable, it's in the current stack frame, not the heap. The stack frame disappears at the end of the current scope. (But it doesn't *really* disappear. It's just undefined behavior to reference it out of scope, so it can return anything.)

Doing it without pointers means more copying (though actually not that much more copying; on a 64-bit system, a pointer is 8 bytes). It also means changes to one copy don't impact the others. That's either good or bad depending on your problem. Getting rid of pointers this way can actually be a very good design as long as the struct doesn't get too big. Once you add pointers, you're going to need to manage memory and decide about ownership and when to free the memory and all the other headaches. It depends on your problem which approach is best.

As a note, if you go this way, there's no reason to create an intermediate `item` (and it's inefficient to do so because it's making two copies of the string). Instead you'd just copy directly into `st`:

```
MyStruct make(char *name) {
    MyStruct st;

    strncpy(st.item.name, name, 10);
    printf("name: %s\n", st.item.name);

    return st;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The `MyStruct st;` is destroyed as soon as the function returns, so that's undefined behavior, so you'll have to use `malloc` and return a pointer to `MyStruct`.</strike>

Actually, returning structs is [perfectly fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653072/return-a-struct-from-a-function-in-c), and the compiler will make sure that a copy of the original data is returned, so no data is lost. But the problem is, the copy is *shallow*, so, for example, pointers are copied literally (the very address the original pointer points to is copied, but not the data), which means that any pointer inside the newly copied struct is potentially invalid, because the memory location it used to point to may have been deallocated while destroying the stack frame on function return.

Your function uses a struct with a pointer inside, and this pointer points to a local variable. The latter is (as all local variables) destroyed on function exit, and while a copy of the original struct is returned, the pointer now points to a memory address that's (probably) no longer controlled by your program.

That's why your data gets overwritten on the second call. So, if you want to preserve `Item item`, you should allocate *it*, and not the return value of your function (although you can do this too, of course, but this won't solve the problem since `item` will be destroyed anyway), on the heap with `malloc`.

Comment: Oh! I have to do it with any variable that will be used after the function is destroyed? Even `int` or just `struct`?

Comment: No, structs can be returned from functions just like ints. Please have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare `Item item;` you're allocating that locally and it falls out of scope. The next function call coincidentally recycles that same memory position.

This is *undefined behaviour* as you need to dynamically allocate that if it's to persist outside that scope.

Comment: How about `MyStruct st`, does it also fall out of scope?

Comment: Anything that's not a pointer and allocated with `malloc` or similar is local *only* and will fall out of scope, however, since you return a copy of it you're avoiding that issue.

Comment: Normal C code will return pointers to structures that have been allocated dynamically and the responsibility for releasing that memory falls on the caller of the function. Yours passes a copy back which is not how C normally works, even though under some narrow conditions it *may* work. Sometimes copying a structure is non-trivial. C++ can do this because it has proper constructors and support for copy/move of complex structures at the language level.

Comment: The real problem with copies is that any dynamically allocated content is not copied properly, just the pointer is. That means that two copies can end up "owning" the same pointer and if one is properly de-allocated then the other ends up holding an invalid pointer. This is flawed by design. You need either proper reference counting (ugly) or a well-defined copy function to effect this properly (better).