# What does a function whose 'return type' is a tag do?

Tags: c, function

I've been learning C for a month now and I've learned/remember that functions are defined like this:

```
return_type function_name( parameter list ) {
     ...body
}
```

But in a lecture about 'list ADTs' the example code which illustrates making and printing a full list there were some pieces of code(function declarations) in a form that I've never seen.

```
...
typedef struct list{ int data; struct list *next; } list;

list* create_list(int d) {
     ...
}
```

To my understanding the return type is ' list '(?) which is a structure tag, and the function name is ' * create_list ' (which is a dereferenced pointer??). I couldn't understand why it was written like that. I want to know how it works and how to use it. How does it differ from other (normal looking)functions like `struct create_list(int d) {...}`? The instructor didn't mention or explain about these so I'm quite confused.

here is the full code just in case

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

typedef struct list{ int data; struct list *next;} list;

int is_empty(const list *l) { return (l == NULL); }

list* create_list(int d) {
    list* head = malloc(sizeof(list));
    head -> data = d;
    head -> next = NULL;
    return head;
}
list* add_to_front(int d, list* h) {
    list* head = create_list(d);
    head -> next = h;
    return head;
}
list* array_to_list(int d[], int size) {
    list* head = create_list(d[0]);
    int i;
    for(i = 1;  i < size; i++) {
        head = add_to_front(d[i], head);
    }
    return head;
}

void print_list(list *h, char *title) {
    printf("%s\n", title);
    while (h != NULL) {
    printf ("%d :", h -> data);
    h = h -> next;
    }
}

int main() {
    list list_of_int;
    list* head = NULL;
    int data[6] = {2,3,5,7,8,9};
    head = array_to_list(data, 6);
    print_list(head, "single element list");
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

any help would be appreciated!

Please correct me if I'm wrong in some point. Thank you

Comment: `To my understanding the return type is ' list '(?) which is a structure tag, and the function name is ' * create_list ' (which is a dereferenced pointer??).` No, the return type is `list*` and the name is `create_list`. `How does it differ from other (normal looking)functions like struct create_list(int d) {...}?` Thats not a normal looking function as its incorrect. `struct` is not a type, `list` is, so is `list*`. You can return a list or a pointer to list, you can't return `struct`.

Comment: @tkausl Thank you! But does that mean a function can never return a struct? (Like when I try to use it in a different situation)

Comment: You [can return a `struct` by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653072/return-a-struct-from-a-function-in-c/9653083), but it can be costly and problematic due to the copying overhead, and its address will keep changing each time it is copied. This is why pointers are often used.

Comment: It's similar to the difference between *declaring* a pointer variable (`int *x;`), and dereferencing this variable (`int a = *x;`). In the former case, you don't say that `*x` is a "dereferenced pointer", but a "pointer to int".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but reading it wrong. Function names do not have things like `*` in them, only types do.

This defines a function that returns `list*` (a.k.a. `struct list*` which is what `typedef` establishes earlier) given argument `d` of type `int`:

```c
list* create_list(int d) {
  // ...
}
```

In other words, `create_list` returns a pointer to `list`. In a type definition `*` means pointer, but it has a different meaning as an *operator*, such as:

```c
int x = 0;
int* y = &x;

*y = 5; // Dereference y pointer, make assignment, in other words, assign to x
```

You can usually spot a dereference operator because it is not part of a type either in a return type specifier, an argument, or a variable declaration. In most other cases it's the dereference operator.

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean 'return head;' in


[ list* create_list(int d) {

     ...return head;

} ]

returns the value(which is a pointer value I believe) to 'list*'?

Comment: Yeah, if `head` is defined as type `list* head` then it'll work out.

Comment: Remember to compile with `-Wall`, or equivalent turned on (Enable "All Warnings") as C is very tricky at the best of times and it's easy to return the wrong type by accident. C will try and do what you *say* not what you *mean* which can often lead to trouble.

Answer (score 1):

> To my understanding the return type is ' list '(?) which is a structure tag

In your example `list` is both a struct tag and a typedef name. The name space rules of C allow four different categories of identifiers:

- lables (for `goto` etc)
- struct/union/enum tags (`struct this_is_a_tag`).
- struct/union members
- everything else

It's valid to name identifiers from these different name spaces the same.

---

In the example

`typedef struct list{ int data; struct list *next;} list;`

the typedef `list` identifier isn't available until at the end of the declaration (after the `;`). The struct tag `struct list` is, however. So the `struct list *next;` member refers to the struct tag, which is a convenient way create a self-referencing struct. Once the typedef is declared, we can either use `list` to refer to the typedef:ed struct type, or we can use `struct list` which means the very same thing - when used outside the struct declaration it's just a style preference which form to use.

So `list* create_list(int d)` is using the typedef `list` to declare the return type of the function as a pointer to struct, `list*`. No different from returning any variable by value vs returning a pointer to it.

In this case the function is calling `malloc` to create a struct variable, so the function needs to return a pointer because anything allocated by `malloc` is always accessed through pointers.