# Getting a segmentation fault in a for loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I read an article on sphere creation for a project of mine that can be found [here](http://blog.andreaskahler.com/2009/06/creating-icosphere-mesh-in-code.html) and decided to try and port it over to c, the language I'm working with. I chose the icosphere method, where you start with an icosahedron, and subdivide from there. The problem is that i get seg faults, but it happens when i try to subdivide it. But if i leave it as is and don't try and subdivide, the code compiles fine no errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct Point
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

struct Triangle
{
    int v1;
    int v2;
    int v3;
};

// normalizes a vertex and then adds it to an array
int add_vertex(struct Point verts[], struct Point point)
{
    double length = (point.x * point.x) + (point.y * point.y) + (point.z * point.z);

    int index = 0;
    
    verts[index].x = point.x / length;
    verts[index].y = point.y / length;
    verts[index].z = point.z / length;
    
    return index++;
}

// gets the middle of a triangle face but checks to make sure that no duplicate vertices are created
int get_middle_point(int p1, int p2, struct Triangle inds[], struct Point verts[], int cache[])
{
    // check to see if the middle point is already calculated
    uint64_t key = (p1 < p2) ? (p1, p2) : (p2, p1);

    if (cache[key] != 0)
    {
        return cache[key];
    }

    // it isn't so calculate it
    struct Point point1 = verts[p1];
    struct Point point2 = verts[p2];
    struct Point middle;
    middle.x = (point1.x + point2.x) / 2.0;
    middle.y = (point1.y + point2.y) / 2.0;
    middle.z = (point1.z + point2.z) / 2.0;

    // add middle vertex to unit sphere
    int i = add_vertex(verts, middle);
    return i;
}

// creates icosphere by subdividing icosahedron
void create_icosphere(int recursion_level, struct Point verts[], struct Triangle inds[])
{
    // cache middle points
    int middle_point_cache[1000];

    // golden ratio
    float t = 1 + sqrt(5) * 0.5;

    // icosahedron cartisean coordinates from wikipedia
    add_vertex(verts, (struct Point){-1, t, 0});
    add_vertex(verts, (struct Point){1, t, 0});
    add_vertex(verts, (struct Point){-1, -t, 0});
    add_vertex(verts, (struct Point){1, -t, 0});

    add_vertex(verts, (struct Point){0, -1, t});
    add_vertex(verts, (struct Point){0, 1, t});
    add_vertex(verts, (struct Point){0, -1, -t});
    add_vertex(verts, (struct Point){0, 1, -t});

    add_vertex(verts, (struct Point){t, 0, -1});
    add_vertex(verts, (struct Point){t, 0, 1});
    add_vertex(verts, (struct Point){-t, 0, -1});
    add_vertex(verts, (struct Point){-t, 0, 1});

    // icosahedron indices

    // 5 faces around point 0
    inds[0] = (struct Triangle){0, 11, 5};
    inds[1] = (struct Triangle){0, 5, 1};
    inds[2] = (struct Triangle){0, 1, 7};
    inds[3] = (struct Triangle){0, 7, 10};
    inds[4] = (struct Triangle){0, 10, 11};

    // 5 adjacent faces
    inds[5] = (struct Triangle){1, 5, 9};
    inds[6] = (struct Triangle){5, 11, 4};
    inds[7] = (struct Triangle){11, 10, 2};
    inds[8] = (struct Triangle){10, 7, 6};
    inds[9] = (struct Triangle){7, 1, 8};

    // 5 faces around point 3
    inds[10] = (struct Triangle){3, 9, 4};
    inds[11] = (struct Triangle){3, 4, 2};
    inds[12] = (struct Triangle){3, 2, 6};
    inds[13] = (struct Triangle){3, 6, 8};
    inds[14] = (struct Triangle){3, 8, 9};

    // 5 adjacent faces
    inds[15] = (struct Triangle){4, 9, 5};
    inds[16] = (struct Triangle){2, 4, 11};
    inds[17] = (struct Triangle){6, 2, 10};
    inds[18] = (struct Triangle){8, 6, 7};
    inds[19] = (struct Triangle){9, 8, 1};

    // subdivide icosahedron
    for (int i = 0; i < recursion_level; i++)
    {
        // create new array for newly created triangle faces
        struct Triangle faces_2[1000];
        int faces_2_index = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            struct Triangle tri = inds[j];

            // get the centroid of each triangle face
            int a = get_middle_point(tri.v1, tri.v2, faces_2, verts, middle_point_cache);
            int b = get_middle_point(tri.v2, tri.v3, faces_2, verts, middle_point_cache);
            int c = get_middle_point(tri.v3, tri.v1, faces_2, verts, middle_point_cache);

            // add new faces to new faces array
            faces_2[faces_2_index++] = (struct Triangle){tri.v1, a, c};
            faces_2[faces_2_index++] = (struct Triangle){tri.v2, b, a};
            faces_2[faces_2_index++] = (struct Triangle){tri.v3, c, b};
            faces_2[faces_2_index++] = (struct Triangle){tri.v1, tri.v2, tri.v3};
        }

        // copy over contents from new array to indices
        for (int j = 0; j < faces_2_index; j++)
        {
            inds[j] = faces_2[j];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    // example usage. works with a subdivision level of 0 but anything higher causes a seg fault
    struct Point vertices[1000];
    struct Triangle indices[1000];
    create_icosphere(2, vertices, indices);
    printf("No errors\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I narrowed the problem down to either the subdivision loop or the `get_middle_point` function (which is called in the subdivision loop). But i don't know why there would be errors there or how to even solve them.
This is currently where my compiler is pointing to for the seg fault
[error in nested subdivide loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk6RW.png) which is inside the subdivision loop.

Comment: `add_vertex()` has a local variable `index` that is always `0`... This is not likely what you intended. Perhaps make it `static` and don't bother returning its value (that is never received by the caller.)

Comment: `struct Triangle faces_2[20 * recursion_level];` When the recusion is `1`, this allocates 20 elements. Then, the index increments 20 * 4 = 80 times, writing well outside of the allocated stack region... You really need to read and think about your code...

Comment: @Fe2O3 ah yes... I just noticed that. I'm gonna change that and see if it works

Comment: @Fe2O3 yes it did seem to work, gonna go post an answer on this right now.

Comment: Now that you've edited the question, it looks like `1000` is your "goto" number when dimensioning an array... This is the sign of a coder who thinks that "completion" trumps "correct"... A very bad habit to be forming...

Comment: @Fe2O3 It's not the size i'm going to keep it's just so that i could show where the error was, why it happened, and how to fix it

Comment: What do you think `uint64_t key = (p1 < p2) ? (p1, p2) : (p2, p1)` will do? Why `uint64_t`? Why the 2 x two comma separated values inside parentheses?

Comment: @Fe2O3 Initially it was `bool firstIsSmaller = p1 < p2;
Int64 smallerIndex = firstIsSmaller ? p1 : p2;
Int64 greaterIndex = firstIsSmaller ? p2 : p1;
Int64 key = (smallerIndex << 32) + greaterIndex;` and was written in C# but I was looking through the article comments and someone made a performance optimization which was `var key = (p1 < p2) ? (p1, p2) : (p2, p1);` that i then ported over to c. The initial point of that chunk of code was to check if the middle point of a given triangle face was already calculated. as for `uint64_t`, that is because i kept getting warnings using `int`/`long`

Comment: It *looks* like you may think `(p1, p2)` is a tuple of some sort, that is not the case in C. Look up comma operator to see what it actually is.

Comment: Based on your description involving `smallerIndex << 32`, It would appear that the "_index_" is used with an array whose dimension is greater than the value of an unsigned integer (and 1/2 of that would be empty)... Lesson: don't simply trust code that you download from the internet...

Comment: @Fe2O3 What would be a better approach to catching duplicates?

Comment: Since `cache[]` is an _uninitialised automatic_ variable (array), its values are indeterminant. And, since this code doesn't store any values into that array, there's no hope the code will _catch duplicates_... I could (jokingly) suggest that `cache[]` become a 2D "1000 x 1000" array of `int`s... `:-)`... Let this be a programming challenge for you.

Comment: I just read the article linked in the OP... Regarding the `<<32`, the author uses a _dictionary_ to store as many _pairs_ as are used... This becomes an auxiliary challenge, in C... Perhaps maintaining a balanced BST?

Comment: @Fe2O3 Whats does bst stand for so i can do some research on it

Comment: "BST": initialism of "Binary Search Tree"... A "balanced BST" would be an expensive mechanism to avoid duplicating a few vertices in this exercise... (Expensive because the example's payload for one node is an 8 byte uint64_t, while each BST node will also required 2x 8byte pointers... Also, maintaining "balance" is a project in itself.)

Answer (score 0):

In the subdivision loop, I created a new array

```
struct Triangle faces_2[20 * recursion_level];
```

but then write out of bounds later on with

```
faces_2[faces_2_index++] = (struct Triangle){tri.v1, a, c};
faces_2[faces_2_index++] = (struct Triangle){tri.v2, b, a};        
faces_2[faces_2_index++] = (struct Triangle){tri.v3, c, b};
faces_2[faces_2_index++] = (struct Triangle){tri.v1, tri.v2, tri.v3};
```

so to solve my problem, I just needed to increase the size

```
struct Triangle faces_2[1000];
```

and it works. I'm keeping it 1000 as a sample size for now but that's soon to change.

Comment: In my first comment I mentioned the value of `index` being always `0`. The rest of the elements of the array will be _undefined_, but treated as floating point values... Next to blow up is the math routines objecting to malformed floating point values.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that the following code does what you think

```
int add_vertex(struct Point verts[], struct Point point) {
    double length = (point.x * point.x) + (point.y * point.y) + (point.z * point.z);

    int index = 0;

    verts[index].x = point.x / length;
    verts[index].y = point.y / length;
    verts[index].z = point.z / length;

    return index++;
}
```

This code accepts an array (pointer to a location in memory) and a "point".  You use the point information to calculate a length (distance in 3D space).  You then create an "index" at 0 and set the fields of the verts array's zeroth element to a value normalized by length.  So far so good (assuming that's your intent).

You then increment 'index' which isn't invalid but it is useless.  You declared index in the function making it a stack allocated variable.  As soon as the function returns all those values disappear.  The next time you call the function you will again set the zero'th element.  The function as given will never set anything other than element [0].

There are a couple of things you can do to correct this but they all affect the structure of the calling code.  One thing is to pass `index` in as a function parameter.  I.E. specify the index value in each call.  If you want to increment the index, you will need to pass the index value as a pointer (`int *index`) and not initialize it inside the function.

It might be cleaner to simply have the function return a Point struct.  HOWEVER to do this you need to understand how memory in C works.  You can refer to this question for help with that: [Return a `struct` from a function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653072/return-a-struct-from-a-function-in-c)

In short, C variables (generally) exist in either "heap" memory (governed by functions like malloc/alloc/free) or on the stack, where they live only as long as the context of the containing function.  Seg-faults occur when you step outside of memory you don't own.  Often when stepping of the end of an array (which are zero relative).

Often a decent debugger can help you understand where the fault is occurring but not why.  The "why" is often simple, but can get very complicated.  Still knowing where can help you backtrace to why.