# function return struct compile failed by gcc, but sccessful by vc6.0

Tags: c, gcc

Why is this failing to compile by gcc, but successfull by vc6.0

gcc version 4.1.2 20070115 (SUSE Linux)

```
linux:~# cc t.c
t.c: In function ‘main’:

t.c:24: error: invalid use of non-lvalue array - printf((confFQDNtolower(&tFQDN)).strName);
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct  {
    char strName[128];
    unsigned short wLen;
}T_FQDN;

T_FQDN confFQDNtolower(T_FQDN *ptFQDN)
{
    static T_FQDN tFQDN = {0};
    int i;

    tFQDN.wLen = ptFQDN->wLen;
    for (i = 0; i < ptFQDN->wLen; i++)
    {
        tFQDN.strName[i] = tolower(ptFQDN->strName[i]);
    }

    return tFQDN;
}

int main()
{
    T_FQDN tFQDN = {"a.B.c", 5};

    printf((confFQDNtolower(&tFQDN)).strName);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This aint C++. It is C.

Comment: Works fine with GCC 4.8.2. What version do you use?

Comment: Why would you ever design a function like that to accept a non-`const` pointer and return a value? Are you actively *trying* to design the least-intuitive interface possible, here? Good job, in that case. :)

Comment: Also, your code is not copying the string terminator, so printing the resulting `strName` will generate undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
printf(&(confFQDNtolower(&tFQDN).strName[0]));
```

See the accepted answer and comments here to understand why this changes things.
 [C - invalid use of non-lvalue array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645624/c-invalid-use-of-non-lvalue-array?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

the only thing you need to change is the printf() line:

```
printf("%s", (confFQDNtolower(&tFQDN)).strName);
```

The above works both with GCC and VisualStudio's CL compilers.

Comment: If the OP's version does work, yours wouldn't either for the OP.

Answer (score -3):

I think should change the code in the following manner.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct  {
    char *strName;
    unsigned short wLen;
}T_FQDN;

T_FQDN confFQDNtolower(T_FQDN *ptFQDN)
{
    static T_FQDN tFQDN = {NULL,0};
    int i;

    tFQDN.wLen = ptFQDN->wLen;

    if(!tFQDN.strName) free(tFQDN.strName);
    tFQDN.strName = strdup(ptFQDN->strName);


    for (i = 0; i < ptFQDN->wLen; i++)
    {
        tFQDN.strName[i] = tolower(tFQDN.strName[i]);
    }


    return tFQDN;
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP do this?

Comment: I can't think of one good reason why this would be a good idea.